# How do I resize windows of selenium remote drivers?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, selenium-remotedriver

I am writing a script to automate form filling which manually take lot of time. And to do this, I wrote a script which automate by launching 4 different [multilogin](https://docs.multilogin.com/l/en/article/ufxks62hb4-selenium-browser-automation) profiles. The issue here is, each driver's window overlap the other one. I want to do resize/positioning of each driver window launched by each one of those 4 tabs in a way shown below.

[image]

Here is the code to launch driver through tkinter gui.

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("SC")
        self.geometry('375x600')
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        names = ['Tab 1', 'Tab 2', 'Tab 3', 'Tab 4']
        self.nb = self.create_notebook(names)
        self.menu = self.create_menus()

        self.mainloop()

    def create_notebook(self, names):
        nb = MyNotebook(self, names)
        self.domain = '127.0.0.1'

        nb.pack()

        def weekly_label(parent):
            label = tk.Label(parent, text="Press to : ")
            label.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=10, pady=10)
            return label

        def weekly_button(parent):
            weekly = ttk.Button(parent, text="Run Weekly Application", width=30,
                                command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=run_weekly, args=(parent,), daemon=True).start())
            weekly.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=10, pady=10)
            return weekly

        def run_weekly(parent):
            port = '54223'
            profile_id = '37c88147-8edc-48da-903b-ca0197b242d9'

            mla_url = 'http://' + str(self.domain) + ':' + str(
                port).strip() + '/api/v1/profile/start?automation=true&profileId=' + str(profile_id).strip()

            resp = requests.get(mla_url)
            jsn = resp.json()

            # #Define DesiredCapabilities
            opts = options.DesiredCapabilities()

            driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=jsn['value'], desired_capabilities={})

        # Add some labels to each tab
        for name in names:
            tab = nb.tabs[name]
            # create a StringVar for this tab

            weekly_label(tab)
            weekly_button(tab)

        return nb

    def create_menus(self):
        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.config(menu=menu)
        subMenu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
        subMenu.add_separator()
        subMenu.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.destroy)
        return menu


class MyNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
    ''' A customised Notebook that remembers its tabs in a dictionary '''

    def __init__(self, master, names):
        super().__init__(master, width=390, height=470)

        # Create tabs & save them by name in a dictionary
        self.tabs = {}
        for name in names:
            self.tabs[name] = tab = ttk.Frame(self)
            self.add(tab, text=name)


GUI()
```

Went through lot of questions here and didn't get any working answer.

Comment: Then don't use `Notebook`.  Just put the 4 frames in a grid.

Comment: @acw1668 will you please show me how's that possible without using `Notebook`?

Comment: @acw1668 what happened, I'm still struggling with this problem!

Comment: As I misunderstand your question, so I removed my answer.

Comment: @acw1668 it was a good effort and I liked the design too.